# how to download search result in csv?

Tags: django, search, csv

I have a query that displays fine in template. Now I need to search that data by user's input and download the searched result in csv. Can anyone help with full example. I have gone through google but not found any solutions. I just found downloading the query in csv not the search result.

Comment: your search result is a query too :)

Comment: see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest example:

```
import csv

@staff_member_required
def get_items_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=items.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2',])
    for item in models.Item.objects.filter(foo=bar);
        writer.writerow([item.col1,item.col2])
    return response
```